# Servlet not being mapped, java web.xml not being overridden in target folder

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

I have 2 servlets in a web project **(Maven)**:

ServletA created in a earlier version of my project (Maven project), works just fine.

ServletB that I've just created after I add (in the properties /Project Facets/Dynamic Web Module 2.4 so it can be recognized as a web project in eclipse)I'm choosing 2.4 beacuse of application server restrictions.

However when I create my servlet I can see the web.xml being mapped with it, **but when I execute mvn clean compile package the web.xml in the target folder is only mapping Servlet A.**

Here is an example of my web.xml´s

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>ServletA</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myDomain.ServletA</servlet-class>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>ServletB</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ServletB</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myDomain.ServletB</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletB</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletB</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletA</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletA</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Any ideas why is ignoring new Servlet's ??**

web.xml in target folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>CredisegurosWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSONRPCServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jabsorb.JSONRPCServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>gzip_threshold</param-name>
      <param-value>200</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSONRPCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/JSON-RPC</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myDomain.ServletA</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletA</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



  <listener>
    <listener-class>myDomain.Inicializador</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- Default 30 min. -->
  <!-- session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config -->
  <filter>
    <display-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myDomain.SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>mx.com.findep.crediseguros.web.comunes.listener.MySessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Ignore the fact that the second web.xml seems to be commentated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it.**

**My Servlet was being mapped in Myproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml**

but when I was executing mvn clean compile package the file read was

**MyProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

I mapped my Servlet manually there **and works**.

If somebody knows why is happening that  ...

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended path is src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml but you also can specify where is  your web descriptor with this :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
     <webXml>${basedir}/path/to/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```