# How to map Servlet in Maven using Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, maven, servlet-mapping

I visited [Servlet not being mapped, java web.xml not being overridden in target folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991326/servlet-not-being-mapped-java-web-xml-not-being-overridden-in-target-folder) and tried to implement.

My web.xml automatically created whenever Servlet added by using Neatbeans interface and resides in `project_folder/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` and has follwing content like below (Default created by Netbeans)-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AdminPathController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>AdminPathController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AdminPathController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AdminPathController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

But when i hit address `localhost:8080/entry-dispatch/AdminPathController` returns an error `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`

Later i put some plugin code in `pom.xml` like below to map the `web.xml` file like below -

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <configuration>
      <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: How do you deploy your application?

Comment: @XtremeBiker When i hit simply `localhost:8080/entry-dispatch/` then welcome page rendered successfully. No deployment Descriptor required to do so..

Comment: And how do you implement `AdminPathController`?

Comment: I add AdminPathController by using netbeans interface, and to map the web.xml i write plugin code in pom.xml.... as given in manual .. @XtremeBiker I am going wrong with above code...

Comment: Well, you need actually a servlet.. Find a good tutorial on how to implement a servlet (there are dozens over the internet).

Comment: What you mean AdminPathController is not a servlet ...?  it's a actual servlet `public class AdminPathController extends HttpServlet {...}`

Comment: is there anyway to define actual servlet other than this @XtremeBiker

Comment: You can't expect people to know you've got a servlet if you don't provide the code in the question.. :-S